# Navigate from a ViewController to another

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, storyboard

I have this design in my storyboard:

[image]

As you see the middle ViewController is connected to a Navigation Controller ( I just made the navigation bar invisible). In this middle page I add all the controls programmatically ( [using Parse mobile platform login wizard](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Protocols/PFLogInViewControllerDelegate.html#//api/name/logInViewController:didLogInUser:) ).

The thing is I want to navigate to the third page, when Login is done successfully.

```
- (void)logInViewController:(PFLogInViewController *)logInController didLogInUser:(PFUser *)user {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    ViewController2 *viewController = [[[ViewController2 alloc] init] autorelease];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    printf("%s", [@"Ali" UTF8String]);
}
```

the message will be printed, but the navigation is failed. Can you help? Perhaps I need to fix something in storyboard.

Comment: Can you check if viedidload of ViewController2 is working. Second shouldn't you be using something like alloc] initWithNibName .

Comment: No does not work. I can't load it that's my question.

Comment: If viewDidLoad is not working can you change your alloc] init TO alloc] initWithNibName and see?

Comment: also have you setup your rootviewcontroller?

Comment: Everything are in storyboard, how can I use NibName?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure you should be sending the `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` message.  Are you presenting another view controller modally on top of your login view controller?

Anyway, when you have configured a view controller in a storyboard, you can't create the view controller using `alloc` and `init`.  You need to ask the storyboard to create it.  There are a couple of ways to do this.

#### One way

One way to get the storyboard to create your `ViewController2` is to make a push segue in your storyboard.

1. Open your storyboard.
2. Control-drag from the login view controller to the `ViewController2`.
3. Choose the “push” segue type.
4. Click on the segue.
5. Choose View > Utilities > Show Attributes Inspector.
6. In the Attributes Inspector (right-hand side of the window), set the segue identifier to “didLogIn”.

To execute the segue, do this:

```
- (void)logInViewController:(PFLogInViewController *)logInController didLogInUser:(PFUser *)user {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"didLogIn" sender:self];
}
```

#### Another way

Another way to get the storyboard to create your `ViewController2` is to give it a storyboard ID and ask the storyboard to instantiate the view controller by ID.  Then you can push the view controller.

Before you can ask the storyboard to create it, you must give a “storyboard ID” to the `ViewController2` instance in your storyboard.

1. Open your storyboard.
2. Select the `ViewController2` instance.
3. Choose View > Utilities > Show Identity Inspector.
4. In the Identity Inspector (right-hand side of the window), enter “viewController2”.  Case is important!

Then, in your code, ask the storyboard to instantiate `viewController2`:

```
- (void)logInViewController:(PFLogInViewController *)logInController didLogInUser:(PFUser *)user {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; // Should this be here?
    ViewController2 *viewController = [[[ViewController2 alloc] init] autorelease];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way,

```
 ViewController2 *myViewController=[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TheNameOfYourController"]
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: I got an error on the storyboard work in the syntax. can you help more?

Answer (score 0):

Because a lot of relevant code/settings is missing I would suggest the following:

1. Use this code:

   ```
   -(void)logInViewController:(PFLogInViewController *)logInController didLogInUser:(PFUser *)user {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    Class klass = [[NSBundle mainBundle] classNamed:@"ViewController2"];
    ViewController2 *viewController = [[klass alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    [viewController release];

    NSLog("%@", @"Ali");
    }
   ```
2. If that doesn't work check how you suppose to initialize ViewController2.

If all this doesn't help please try to post more relevant code.

Comment: Doesn't work. check this link maybe it can be helpful: https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Protocols/PFLogInViewControllerDelegate.html#//api/name/logInViewController:didLogInUser:

Answer (score 0):

**To move next viewController using Storyboard Identifier**

```
nextViewController *objnextViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"nextViewControllerIdentifier"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController: objnextViewController animated:YES];
```